# Accessing javascript functions defined in different files

Tags: javascript, callback, dojo, color-palette

I am having two seemingly related problems accessing javascript function defined in different places.  The first problem I am having is calling function I have defined from the console of firgbug or safari.  I defined a function called getRed the looks like this:

```
    function getRed(row, col)
    {
           // do something stuff and return the red value as a float
    }
```

I would like to be able to test this function from the console but every time I try and call getRed(1,1); for example, I get an error like this: ReferenceError: getRed is not defined

Do I need to make a special call to define the namespace?  I define this function in a javascript file called drawing.js which is define very early in my html page.

The other problem I am having is calling a function defined in that same drawing.js file from the onChange: method of my dojo color palette.  Here is the code for the color palette:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="drawing.js"></script>
 //the method colorChange is inside drawing.js which is defined before the dojo 
 //color palette
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojox.widget.ColorPicker");
        dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
            var c = new dojox.widget.ColorPicker({
                onChange: function(val)
                {
                    console.log("BEFORE");
                    colorChange(val);
                    console.log("AFTER");
                }
            },
            "picker1");
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the definition of changeColor inside the file drawing.js:

```
    function colorChange(val)
{
    console("colorChange!");
}
```

Every time I click on the color palette I get the following error: ReferenceError: colorChange is not defined.

I am very new to javascript and I am sure that these two issue have a very similar and easy solution but I have not been able to find the answer online.  Can anyone help me out?

I am pretty sure the script is being loaded as this screen shot shows:
[image]

Comment: Does drawing.js implement a class?  My guess is that `colorChange` is not in the global scope, because it's defined within a class..

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, looking at the way the functions are indented in drawings.js.  Are you sure it isnt something like foo.colorChange() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Console is in the same global scope as your page. Since `getRed()` and `colorChange()` are both defined in drawing.js and neither can be found in the global scope, I suspect drawing.js is not being properly included.

To check that drawing.js is actually included (i.e. and you have the file path correct), go to Firebug's Script tab. It'll list all scripts included on the current page.

Comment: I'm not trying to call a function defined in the console. I'm trying to call a function defined in a javascript src file from the console.

Comment: It also looks like the script has been loaded (I just added a screenshot that shows this).

Comment: Hmm.. I created a quick mockup using your exact script tags with a getRed() defined in a drawing.js and it works. Are any other functions defined in drawing.js undefined? Or are these two functions defined within another function?

Comment: Mmm you were correct I was defining those functions nested inside another function... duh.  Thank you so much!  It works now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for extra configuration, all you need is to make sure that your drawing.js is included, check if the path to the file is correct. If its correct that there should be no problems with the invoke.

Just check is your js location real, if your js file is in root just add slash in front of location so it will load it always from www.example.com/drawing.js Add attribute language="javascript" to your <script ....

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thats' strange, drawing.js defines all of the functions and event handling for a little canvas based 2d pixel editor and all of that works but I still cannot call the functions from the callback or the console.  drawing.js is in the same location as my html file so I think src="drawing.js" should be correct.